# How to customize id

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Hi i just want to ask on how to customize id. Like i want to add some 0’s at the beginning. For Eg. ”0000151”. Because when i add 0000151 as an id. Only 151 appears in the table the 0’s doesn’t appear.

Here is my code in inserting id to database :

Private Function AddUser()

```
    Access.AddParam("@ID", txtID.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@Course", cbxCourse.SelectedItem)
    Access.AddParam("@Yr", cbxYear.SelectedItem)
    Access.AddParam("@Fname", txtFname.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@Lname", txtLname.Text)
    Access.AddParam("@Mname", txtMname.Text)


         Access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO StudentInformation ( ID, Course, Yr, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName) ; ")



    MsgBox("Student was added successfully.")
    Form1.RefreshGrid()
    Me.Close()
```

End sub

Comment: Numbers dont have leading zeds except when formatted that way *as text*.  Users dont usually see/know/enter the DB Id, it is usually something the DB assigns.

Answer (score 2):

As Plutonix wrote, assigning semantic value to an autonumber or autoindex attribute is not a best practice. If you still want to do that, I suggest that you add the leading zeroes when you display the value to the user: on forms and reports. In the underlying table it will not have the leading zeroes. You can write a little VBA to add the padding at display time:

```
Format(ID, "0000000")
```

for a 7 character wide field, right-justified, zero padded from the left.

Comment: Wherever you _display_ the values.